# JavaScript: How to build key-value pairs

Tags: javascript

In jQuery you can pass key-value pairs like this

```
$(this).colorbox({ width:100, height:500 });
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to build such key-value pair, eg. something like this

```
var pairs = ???;

if(someCondition)
  pairs.Add('width', '100');
else
  pairs.Add('maxWidth', '200');

$(this).colorbox(pairs);
```

Comment: You can store another object. Something like `pair = new Object();` `pair.width = 100`, then call it with `pair.width`.

Comment: Question is not clear. Are you trying to add item to an existing object?

Comment: No. By 'build such key-value pair' I mean to create the key-value pairs to be passed to the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var obj = {};
obj[key] = value;
```

You create an object, then assign your values under your keys.

Answer (score 1):

There's no prototyped method to do this, but you'd probably just use regular property access capabilities...

```
if(someCondition)
  pair.width = '100';
else
  pair.maxWidth = '200';
```

Comment: `Object.prototype.add = function(name, value) { this[name] = value};` :-)

Comment: Ah, the 8th deadly sin. You brave soul! ;)